# La animación no funciona con JS

Tags: javascript, animación, animacion-css

Quisiera una ayuda por favor.

Quiero hacer un menú desplegable animado con `js`, he creado un objeto para controlarlo al darle la primera función en la que el menú desplegable baja lo hace con normalidad, pero al darle la segunda función `closenav()` (de cerrar e menú donde sube a su provisión inicial) la animación no funciona.

```
export class Nav {
    constructor(x, bar, menu, container) {

        this.x = x;
        this.bar = bar;
        this.menu = menu;
        this.container = container;
    }
    openNav() {
        const menu = this.menu;
        const container = this.container
        this.bar.addEventListener("click", function() {

            menu.style.display = "flex";
            menu.animate([
                // keyframes
                {
                    transform: 'translateY(-100%)',
                    opacity: 0
                },
                {
                    transform: 'translateY(0)',
                    opacity: 1,

                }
            ], {
                // timing options
                duration: 3000
            })
            menu.style.top = "0";



        }, true);


    }

    closeNav() {
        const x = document.querySelector("#x");
        const menu = this.menu;
        const container = this.container
        x.addEventListener("click", function() {


            menu.animate([
                // keyframes
                {
                    transform: 'translateY(0)',
                    opacity: 1
                },
                {
                    transform: 'translateY(-100%)',
                    opacity: 0,


                }
            ], {
                // timing options
                duration: 3000
            }, true)



        }, false);



    }

}
const nav = new Nav(x, bar, menu_mobile, container);

nav.openNav();
nav.closeNav();
```

Comment: Estás en SO en español traduce por favor

Comment: Lo siento, quisiera una ayuda por favor quiero hacer un  menú desplegable animado con js, he creado un objeto para controlarlo al darle la primera función en la que el menú desplegable baja lo hace con normalidad pero al darle la segunda función (de cerrar e menú donde sube a su provisión iniial) la animación no funciona.

Comment: Hola, bienvenido a la comunidad. Te invito a hacer el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y leer [¿cómo preguntar?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tu pregunta sea bien recibida por parte de la comunidad. Además, para poder reproducir tu problema y encontrar una solución fácilmente nos sería de gran ayuda un [ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Dicho esto, necesitaríamos conocer el código HTML para saber versión de jQuery, cómo está estructurado el menú desplegable, etc para poder probar nosotros y poder arreglarlo.